# Manual Merge to Different Commits in Git

Tags: git

I have a hierarchy of commits in my local repo and I want to roll back to an old commit and apply some, not all, of the changes from the HEAD commit. How do I do this?

Consider the following scenario. I have the following commits in my repo:

> Commit 6 (HEAD)
>   Commit 5
>   Commit 4
>   Commit 3
>   Commit 2
>   Commit 1

I reset to commit 2 as below

```
git reset --hard commit2
```

Now I want, for example, to merge all the changes applied up until commit 6 but without those in commit 3 and with some of those in commit 5.

If I do this:

```
git merge commit6
```

I will end up having everything in the HEAD without the selectiveness I am after.

How can I achieve my target?

Cheers
AF

Comment: thanls for ur replies. am trying rebase but now am stuck in the Terminal! i am stick in a text entry mode in Terminal that has some command options text in it and noop! i want to exit but do not know how. tried everything but not working. Besides i did not get a prompt up of the interactive editor

Comment: ok i released that my editor was actually VIM which was open in the Terminal (on Mac). Am was familiar with it thats why i was confused. Managed to get the file saved and now in the process of performing the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use rebasing

You don't need to reset to commit 2

In your HEAD, type

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6
```

And interactive editor will be prompted up.

You can manipulate how's your commit would look like 
e.g. Delete the line commit 3

Save it

then your target result is what you are looking for

Comment: thanls for ur replies. am trying rebase but now am stuck in the Terminal! i am stick in a text entry mode in Terminal that has some command options text in it and thats it! i want to exit but do not know how. tried everything but not working. Besides i did not get a prompt up of the interactive editor

Comment: I am getting there now. i can combine commits and delete them. But how can i do an edit to the changes i made in any commit? If i do "edit" in the interactive rebase file i get to a state where i edit the message o the commit but not the changes i made. How do i proceed from there?

Comment: @Abolfoooud: so far as i Know, you need to delete and recreate that commit. You can reorder your desired commit to the HEAD. Then you git reset --hard HEAD^ to made the changes again.

Comment: Cheers for that... i ended up doing this manually. I was hopping there is a better way. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You may either `cherrypick` commits that you want.

Or use interactive rebase if you want to modify history in place (should never be done if you have already upstreamed your changes):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6
# in editor that popped up remove line that corresponds to Commit3, save and quit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new branch with just the selected commits.

```
git checkout branch
git checkout -b new_branch

# remove unwanted commits
git rebase -i HEAD~6

# continue with merge
```

Or you can always cherry pick commits.